# want to show kendo column value with specific Contains value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid + mvc 5. in that,

```
columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate..
```

I just want to use "Contains".

`if "SitePlanMediaUrl.Contains(\"" + ViewBag.option + "\"))"` value then `ClientTemplate` item show, otherwise not.

note - I have a value in "ViewBag.option"

-code line -

```
columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("download", "common", new { area = "" }) + "?url=#=SitePlanMediaUrl#&fileName=#=MediaTitle#' title='Download Media' class='icon download' target='_blank'></a> #if(SitePlanMediaUrl.Contains(\"" + ViewBag.option + "\"))  {#  <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='icon upload' onclick='SitePlanUploadMedia(#=SitePlanMediaId#,\"#=MediaTitle#\", \"#=MediaTitle#\")' title='Upload Media'></a> #}# <a href='javascript: void(0)' class='icon delete' onclick='deleteRowConfirm(\"sitePlanMediagrid\",this)' title='Delete Media'></a>").Title("Action").Width(50);
```

if I get in between SitePlanMediaUrl then tag will show.

thanks.

Comment: Could you format your *code* better? I don't understand what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: this is kendo grid column line, & my condition -  

columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate("#if(SitePlanMediaUrl.Contains(\"" + ViewBag.option + "\"))  {#  <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='icon upload' onclick='SitePlanUploadMedia(#=SitePlanMediaId#,\"#=MediaTitle#\", \"#=MediaTitle#\")' title='Upload Media'></a> #}# ").Title("Action").Width(50);

& i got Error -  VM2424:3 Uncaught TypeError: SitePlanMediaUrl.Contains is not a function

Comment: I suspect this is not translated to C#, but instead to javascript. Could you try with 
if(SitePlanMediaUrl.indexOf(\"" + ViewBag.option + "\") > -1) ?

Comment: ya..its working ... thanku very very much.....

Comment: I'll give it as an answer to help other identify the same problem. Please mark it as accepted, if it really worked for you, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is not translated to C#, but to javascript, due to this being a ClientTemplate in the kendo framework.

Could you try with `if(SitePlanMediaUrl.indexOf(\"" + ViewBag.option + "\") > -1)` 
.

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.